# HTML5 input type date is not loading the date value from the controller in ASP.NET Core 1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html, razor

I am trying to load today's date into the HTML5 date input type in Core 1.1, however when I set today's date in the controller, I get the following error in the console on the page.

> The specified value "9/3/2017 12:00:00 AM" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".

AddWorkOrder.cshtml

```
<div class="form-group">
    <b>Issue Date:</b>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.NewWorkOrder.workOrderIssueDate, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "date", @value = Model.NewWorkOrder.workOrderIssueDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.NewWorkOrder.workOrderIssueDate, "", new { @class = "valColor" })
</div>
```

WorkOrderController.cs

```
// GET : /WorkOrder/AddWorkOrder
public IActionResult AddWorkOrder()
{
    WorkOrderViewModel workOrderVm = new WorkOrderViewModel();
    using (var db = new WorkOrderDBContext())
    {
        workOrderVm.NewWorkOrder = new WorkOrder();
        workOrderVm.NewWorkOrder.workOrderIssueDate = DateTime.Today;
    }
    return View(workOrderVm);
}
```

I have tried setting the value of the textbook to be `@value = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` and that does not load the date either.

Comment: Have you tried to make `workOrderIssueDate` property as `string` and convert the `DateTime.Today` to string like the following `workOrderVm.NewWorkOrder.workOrderIssueDate = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`?

Comment: I have multiple date fields and they are all DateTime's in MSSQL database tables. I would like to keep them DateTime if possible so that all of the fields in my database are not all strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use data-format attribute like this for post correct format date:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.NewWorkOrder.workOrderIssueDate, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @class = "form-control", @type = "date" })
```

Comment: Tried this, got an error on `@data-format = "yyyy-MM-dd"`  in visual studios saying "The name 'format' does not exist in the current context.  Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member argument, simple name or member access."

Comment: Do you know what the format would be for time would be? It is not loading the time and has a similar error of The specified value "14:29:45.9712712" does not conform to the required format.  The format is "HH:mm", "HH:mm:ss" or "HH:mm:ss.SSS" where HH is 00-23, mm is 00-59, ss is 00-59, and SSS is 000-999.  `@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.NewWorkOrder.workOrderProcessTime, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "time" })`

Comment: Figured it out, it's `{0:hh\\:mm}`

Answer (score 0):

I was having a very similar problem but I had a clue because I had two dates on my input form and one was working while the other wasnt. I got very confused because the HTML and the Razor markup was exactly the same. Then I noticed that for the date that wasnt working as expected, I decorated the attribute in the model wtih

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
```

but for the value that worked correctly I decorated that as

```
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
```

Once I changed them both to be DateTime, the error went away. I don't pretend to understand why.